# Why when i try to use a winform in a threadpool it gives me an error saying scaledev is a type?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to wrap my head around how to make this work but the scenario is I have a main Winform and on that winform I have many options to set and I also have a FlowLayoutPanel.

This is a simple ftp transfer program but it's purpose is to be able to transfer to multiple machines at a time that works off of a list that could be 2 devices or 6000 devices or more.

Anyway I am having trouble with the threading part. I ultimately would like the code to create a winform and insert it into the panel being completely in its own thread for the ftp transfer and update the progress bar and then when finished removed from the main panel and start the next one based on the max connections property.

I am looking at threadpooling to keep my connections limited to each device and this is what I am trying to do so far but it doesn't seem to want to accept an object like the examples I have seen online.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ScaleDev), i);
```

ScaleDev is the Winform I am trying to use and que in a threadpool

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace Multicopy
{
    public partial class ScaleDev : Form
    {
        public Int16 ControlID { get; set; }
        public String StoreID { get; set; }
        public String IP { get; set; }
        public String Filename { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
        public String source { get; set; }
        public String dest { get; set; }


        public ScaleDev()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public ScaleDev(FlowLayoutPanel panel)
        {
            

        }


        private void Scale_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void BeginTransfer()
        {
            string ftpServer = "ftp://" + source;
            string ftpUsername = "";
            string ftpPassword = "";
            string sourceFile = source;
            string remoteFile = dest; //Filename located in csv
            int maxConnections = 1;

            // Create a new FTP request for the file transfer
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer + "/" + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);

            // Enable multithreaded transfer
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = false;
            ftpRequest.ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            ftpRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = maxConnections;

            // Create an input stream for the source file
            using (Stream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
            {
                // Set the FTP request's content length to the source file's length
                ftpRequest.ContentLength = sourceStream.Length;

                // Start uploading the file using multiple threads
                Parallel.ForEach(new[] { sourceStream }, stream =>
                {
                    using (Stream ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytes = 0;
                        while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            Console.WriteLine("File transfer completed successfully!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

I tried Parralel and threads.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: `public partial class ScaleDev` - `ScaleDev` is a type.

Comment: Why do you output to console in a WinForms app?

Comment: Please disregard the console line as I was just testing the code outside to make sure the ftp part was working. This biggest problem and like what Guru said It is a type. Can I do anything to make that work? Also the error message I am getting AKX is Error CS0119 and it complains about it being a type and that it's not valid in the given context

Comment: I may be approaching this in a completely wrong way. I haven't dealt with thread pools before so again any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ahh I think I may have finally figured it out. Instead of running multiple instances of the form directly I can do this within a method returning void instead.